# Final part of my dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Ok so thanks to people here I have nearly completed my dropdown to the standard of a 3 year old. I know that there is probably a way to shorten and streamline my code so any pointers would be great.  Here is all my code and a jsfiddle will be at the bottom:

oh and before I forget is there a way that I can smooth out the animations? like a wait() kind of deal that will make the slide down wait until the slide up is complete?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/formhandler.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="CSS/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$('a#1').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').is(":visible")) {
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    if ($('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul#1').is(":visible")) {
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').slideUp(300);
    } else {
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul#1').slideToggle(300);
    }
});
$('a#2').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').is(":visible")) {
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    if ($('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul#2').is(":visible")) {
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').slideUp(300);
    } else {
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul#2').slideToggle(300);
    }
});
$('a#3').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').is(":visible")) {
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    if ($('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul#3').is(":visible")) {
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').slideUp(300);
    } else {
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul#3').slideToggle(300);
    }
});
$('a#4').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').is(":visible")) {
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    if ($('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul#4').is(":visible")) {
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul').slideUp(300);
    } else {
        $('#mid-nav > ul').find('ul#4').slideToggle(300);
    }
});
```

});

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="topbanner"></div>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="navigation">
      <div id="topnav">
        <div id="left-side">
          <div id="left-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link l1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link l2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="logo"><img src="images/general/nav_logo.png" /> </div>
        <div id="right-side">
          <div id="right-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link r1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link r2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mid-nav">
        <ul id="midnav">
          <li><a href="#" >HOME</a></li>
          <li><a id="1" href="#" >ABOUT</a>
            <ul id="1">
              <li><a href="#">test1.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">test1.3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">test1.1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a id="2"href="#">Work</a>
            <ul id="2">
              <li><a href="#">test1x.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">test1x.3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">test1x.1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a id ="3" href="#">Clients</a>
            <ul id="3">
              <li><a href="#">test2.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">test2.3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">test1.2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a id="4"href="#">Contact</a>
            <ul id="4">
              <li><a href="#">test3.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">test3.3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">test3.1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--START 100% HERE!--> 
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="social-images"><img src="images/socialmedia/facebook.gif" height="40" width="40"/></div>
  <div class="social-images"><img src="images/socialmedia/google.gif" height="40" width="40"/></div>
  <div class="social-images"><img src="images/socialmedia/twitter.gif" height="40" width="40"/></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


CSS:

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* NAVIGATION */
#wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -100px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
#topbanner{
    width:100%;
    height:54px;
    background-color:#f1f2f2;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1000;
}
#topnav {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1050px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    background-color: #f1f2f2;
}
#left-side {
    float: left;
    width: 439px;
}
#right-side {
    float: right;
    width: 439px;
}
#logo {
    padding-top: 7px;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
}
#left-menu {
}
#left-menu ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
#left-menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#left-menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'AftasansRegular';
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    border: none;
}
#right-menu {
}
#right-menu ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
#right-menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#right-menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'AftasansRegular';
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    border: none;
}
ul#midnav {
    border-width: 1px 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid thin #c8c8c8;
}
ul#midnav li {
    display: inline;
}
ul#midnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'AftasansRegular';
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    border: none;
}
ul#midnav li ul{
line-height: 30px;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0; top:100px;
 display: none;/* --Hide by default--*/
 width:100%;
 height:40px;
 background: #fff;
    border-bottom: solid thin #c8c8c8;



}


/* NAVIGATION END */
/* FOOTER BEGIN */
#footerwrapper, #push {
    height: 100px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
    background-color: #f1f2f2;
}
#footer {
        border-top: solid thin #c8c8c8;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f1f2f2;
}
#social-wrapper {
    width: 130px;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}
.social-images {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #f1f2f2;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
}
/*FOOTER END *?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XN4vf/

Sorry if this is coded like a moron (I'm still using my training wheels).

Thanks

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you should use CSS classes instead of ids for the `a` tags that trigger the slideToggle on their respective submenus. Also, ids in a valid HTML page are expected to be unique and you use the same id "1", "2", etc. for different elements. More importantly, though, by using classes you don't need to bind the onclick event for all the anchor tags separately, which saves a lot of code ;-)

Here is the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XN4vf/3/

The relevant code is this:

```
  $("a.slide").on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().siblings().find("ul:visible").slideUp();
   $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(300);
  });
```

Once you give the `a` tags a class called "slide" or similar, you can rewrite your event callback to first hide / slideUp all the submenus belonging to the **siblings of the currently clicked a tag**. After that, you trigger the `slideToggle()` to show or hide the **current** submenu. That way, if you first click on ABOUT and then without clicking on ABOUT again (and triggering the toggle) you click on WORK for instance, then the submenu changes correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer has made me understand a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#midnav li a').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#midnav li ul').slideUp(300);
        var ul = $(this).parent().find('ul');
        if(ul.is(':visible')){
            ul.slideUp(300);
        }else{
            ul.slideDown(300);
        }
   });
});
```